# Did Adam and Eve have sex with the serpent question

Tags: discussion, moderation

There was a question that said something along the lines of

"I heard that the original sin was that Adam and Eve had sex with the serpent. What do y'all think about that?"

The question disappeared (was deleted?) before any attempts were made to clarify or help the user ask an appropriate, on-topic question. Why?

Granted, it was a truth question, it doesn't seem like that's a common practice. It seems to me that the question, once rewritten from a "biblical bases" or "denominational standpoint" would have been a valid question, with a valid answer in the negative. It felt to me a bit cowardly to just get rid of it immediately. What gives?

Comment: Downvoted for describing an absolutely sensible moderative action as 'cowardly'.

Comment: In what way was deleting the question cowardly? Of what do you think the moderator was fearful and cowering?

Comment: Also your premise that no attempt was made to help the user is wrong. They were at least linked to the help section and pointed in the direction they need to look to understand what went wrong and how to ask proper questions. They will still see those comments even though you can't as you don't have the rep to see deleted posts. They can see their own and will have the comment notifications in their inbox.

Comment: @Caleb That's good to know, and really resolves my main concern. Thank you.

Comment: @Flimzy I think the moderator was personally offended by the question and fearful of broaching the subject of sex in that context on Christianity.SE.

Comment: @Andrew There's lots of sex questions. I didn't see the original, but, assuming it needed to be closed for format and such, then I think a delete was in order too. That kind of question, when not formatted well for this site, is a very big ball of troll bait. Deletion, like closure, is not permanent, and has been undone in the past, after edits and whatever.

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't offended at all. My first thought was "where on Scripture is this even remotely hinted at?".  Then reading it, the next was "Some guy said? The basis is some guy said?".  The rest of my thoughts are pretty much exactly what I put in this answer. I wasn't offended at all, it's just such a wild left-field question with such a shaky premise and written at a middle-school level that a low-quality delete seemed like a no-brainer

Comment: @Andrew why would you think someone would've been offended by that question? It wasn't offensive, just stupid.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think any of our moderators are offended by sex.

Comment: @Andrew We have a very clear policy about sex questions: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3898/1039 If it is related to theology, we keep them - but we have a lot, and many of them aren't on topic. The linked question was nothing but heresay, and not really on topic in and of itself. The sex bit was irrelevant to its deletion

Answer (score 10):

I deleted it as low quality. The premise was "some guy said" followed by one of the most ridiculous questions I've ever seen on this site. If we were foolish enough to allow that type of question to stand, we open the site up to any mocking, ridiculous, offensive questions imaginable.

- Did Jesus pick his nose? some guy said He did, and I'm wondering if it's valid.
- Does God watch Scooby Doo? Some guy said he did.

No way.  This is supposed to be a site for professional questions. It's not a free-for-all and letting that foolishness to stand would be a horrible precedent.

Comment: I completely agree on the nature of the question and that it needed deleting, my only comment would be that mostly for the sake of the paper trail and a clear message to the Q owner I think I would have closed it before deleting. It had pending close votes already so that would have added more names that just yours to the action as well.

Comment: Thank you, @Caleb. You're right.

Comment: I've seen and myself started successful questions with things I've seen and heard from people who self identify as christians. This wasn't a goofy question about cartoons or nose picking, but about the relationship between sexual immorality and the sin in the garden. One could easily write a mature and professional question that asks the same thing within an acceptable question format, which I will now demonstrate.

Comment: please see [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32913/was-cain-a-descendant-of-the-serpent-through-eve).

Comment: That's a lot different than "some guy said". Your question wouldn't have been unilaterally deleted.It's much higher quality.

Comment: @davidstratton I was in the process of doing the same thing in an edit for the original question when it was deleted. If it was closed, I could have edited it then moved to re-open. Can you please ping the original asker in the new question so that person can benefit from reading the answers? Thank you.